# Why is $Y_n$ of that form?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $R$ be any integral domain of characteristic zero.
We consider the Pell equation $$X^2-(T^2-1)Y^2=1\tag 1$$ over $R[T]$. Let $U$ be an element in the algebraic closure of $R[T]$ satisfying $$U^2=T^2-1\tag 2$$ Define two sequences $X_n, Y_n, n=0, 1, 2, \dots $, of polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}[T]$, by setting $$X_n+UY_n=(T+U)^n\tag 3$$

**Lemma 1.**

The solutions of $(1)$ in $R[T]$ are given precisely by $$X=\pm X_n , Y=\pm Y_n ,\ n=0, 1, 2, \dots$$

We write $V \sim W$ to denote that the polynomials $V$ and $W$ in $R [T]$ take the same value at $T = 1$. Notice that the relation $Z \sim 0$ is diophantine over $R [T]$ with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}[T]$, indeed $$Z \sim 0 \leftrightarrow \exists X \in R[T]: Z=(T-1)X$$

**Lemma 2.**

We have $Y_n \sim n$, for $n=0, 1, 2, \dots $.

*Proof.*

From $(3)$ and $(2)$ follows $$Y_n=\sum_{i=1,\ i \text{ odd }}^{n}\binom{n}{i}(T^2-1)^{(i-1)/2}T^{n-i}$$ Substitute now $T=1$.

$$$$

Could you explain to me the proof of the Lemma $2$?

I haven't understood it...

Why is $Y_n$ of that form?

Answer (score 0):

From $(3)$
$$
\begin{align*}
X_n+UY_n&=\sum_{i=0}^n {n \choose i}T^{n-i}U^i\\
&=\sum_{\substack{i=0\\i\text{ even}}}^n {n \choose i}T^{n-i}U^i+\sum_{\substack{i=1\\i\text{ odd}}}^n {n \choose i}T^{n-i}U^i\\
&=\sum_{\substack{i=0\\i\text{ even}}}^n {n \choose i}T^{n-i}(U^2)^{i/2}+U\sum_{\substack{i=1\\i\text{ odd}}}^n {n \choose i}T^{n-i}U^{i-1}\\
&=\sum_{\substack{i=0\\i\text{ even}}}^n {n \choose i}T^{n-i}(T^2-1)^{\frac{i}{2}}+U\sum_{\substack{i=1\\i\text{ odd}}}^n {n \choose i}T^{n-i}(U^2)^{\frac{i-1}{2}}\\
X_n+UY_n&=\left(\sum_{\substack{i=0\\i\text{ even}}}^n {n \choose i}T^{n-i}(T^2-1)^{\frac{i}{2}}\right)+U\left(\sum_{\substack{i=1\\i\text{ odd}}}^n {n \choose i}T^{n-i}(T^2-1)^{\frac{i-1}{2}}\right).\\
\end{align*}
$$
Then, comparing coefficients (both sides are like polynomials in $U$) we obtain
$$
X_n=\sum_{\substack{i=0\\i\text{ even}}}^n {n \choose i}T^{n-i}(T^2-1)^{\frac{i}{2}}
$$
and
$$
Y_n=\sum_{\substack{i=1\\i\text{ odd}}}^n {n \choose i}T^{n-i}(T^2-1)^{\frac{i-1}{2}}.
$$